# How would you animate this (Video example)

Tags: python, animation, particles, geometry-nodes, physics

I'm trying to animate this with meta-balls for a few days now. First i tried it with reguals spheres and cloth physics but i think the effect meta balls give is good enough.
My main issue is how do i animate the spheres flying around?
The first thought i had was with particles and force fields but when i'm using force fields i don't have much control and the balls fly away.
I wan't them to orbit kinda random and also have control over the speed.
Does anybody know a solution how i can achieve this?

[Original Xbox intro 1080p HD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-ZPF0o_8j8&ab_channel=MonkeyFlop)

[image]

Comment: If physics or boids are too unpredictable you could simply keyframe

Comment: “when i'm using force fields i don't have much control and the balls fly away” two potential issues causing this, one, you might not have turned off gravity which would make them fall, and two you might not have set the force field to attract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like old-school meatballs ... animation can be done many ways.

Here is one

- add Icosphere (Sub 1, by default set 2)
- parent MBall to Icosphere and under Icosphere's *Object Properties*  enable *Instances* from *Vertices*
- add *Displace* modifier > Texture > Cloud

[image]

- animate Icospheres Rotation (by keyframes or easier by driver - click into axis field and type `#frame*0.2` ... to control speed adjust value 0.2

[image]

[image]